# responsive web design not working properly

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

Im trying to make my website responsive but when i try and change the css styles for the different sizes some of them are not working and im not sure why.

I have styled my website and then used the following line and it works perfectly fine when the size of the screen reaches 1680

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1680) {

    css style...

}
```

but when i try and do it for the next size it doesn't resize:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1366) {

     Everything that i put in here doesn't work 
}
```

Am i doing something wrong here?

Are they supposed to be in the same class or does it not matter as long as i link the class to the html document?

Comment: You missed `px` in media queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you forgot the "px".

Generally speaking, you may want to define a range, such as:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) and (max-width: 1680px) {

}
```

As-is, any css you have in the 1366px media query should display between 0px and 1366px.

Answer (score 0):

You had been forgotten to put `px` after your number.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1680px) {
    css style...
}
```